# Trying To deploy JavaFX app to MAC app store showing Sandbox error

Tags: macos

> ERROR ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list: [( "123123123client.pkg/Payload/123123123Client.app/Contents/MacOS/123123123Client", "123123123client.pkg/Payload/123123123Client.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jspawnhelper" )] Refer to App Sandbox page at https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/ for more information on sandboxing your app."

Although i have added the sand box entitlement in info plist .but still getting the same...any help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a legitimate solution ....but it solve the purpose that i needed as Since the application is build using JAVA FX i am not able to pinpoint the concern in the build (JAVA APP was developed by Some else and i got the responsibility to submit it to app store since only ios resource in the company :)) . After struggling for day and using various approach to get this work.

I come up with approach  where i created a blank project with same build added the app icons ,then sandbox enable for app and the frameworks and then compiled the build got the xcode archive.then i have replaced the project.app with javafx .but before replacing the same i have replaced the info.plist first as after all info.plist have all the settings required.

after doing so i tried uploading the build and surprisingly it work and build uploaded to the app store.

Now the Mac Application is under review....